# 500 (Internal Server Error) in Laravel while trying to send Mail

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I want to make an online appointment in my Laravel project. For that I have generated a mail function for the appointment.This mail function is working in xammp server....But not in live server.

Got this error while trying to send mail

```
GET http://sencare.com.bd/sencare.com.bd/confirm_appointment?patient_name=test&patient_number=01654&patient_email=rahmanarafat13%40gmail.com&patient_age=8&patient_gender=1&service_id=6&schedule_time_id=1&date=+2018-03-27 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4
n.(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ (index):2029
dispatch @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
```

Mail function code inside controller

```
 public function sendMail($emailDataArray)
{
    \Mail::send('frontend.mail.demo', $emailDataArray, function($message) use ($emailDataArray)
    {
        $message->to($emailDataArray['patient_email'], 'Test')->subject('APPOINTMENT');
    });
}
```

Here `$emailDataArray` is an array with the data of from, to and others.

Is there any mistake ?

Comment: @HH... No it's not ...

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error `'Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com'` which can be seen if you open the Network tab and looking at the response error when you try to book an appointment.

This is most likely due to not setting up your mail service properly. Make sure you have all the correct `.env` variables and details in the `config/mail.php` set

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail

Comment: Will you please give me more specific correction in .enc file ?

Answer (score 0):

Just put SMTP details in `.env` file then try once again.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.mailhost.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: .....`ERROR: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110] {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110] at /home2/sencarec/public_html/sencare.com.bd/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:269)`

Comment: It seems all settings all correct. You need to check SMTP credentials which you provided in .env file.

Comment: here is my `.env` file 
`
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=shetshuvro@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=yplxqvhpoxjzuiml
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl`

Comment: Change `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls` then run this command `php artisan config:cache` then try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167227/discussion-between-sateesh-and-raff).

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem.

Just change the driver name in `.env` file from `smtp` to `sendmail`

```
'driver' => 'sendmail',
```